# execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given (MySQLi)?

Tags: php, mysqli

During my paths of coding in Mysqli I have been stumped and can't seem to figure out what the error is trying to say:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/test/private_html/test.php on line 58
```

The code I have tried to fix many times is as so

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  `test_table`(datenow,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8, 
test9,test10,test11,test12,test14,test15,test16,test17,test18,) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") 
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss',$test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6,$test7,$test8,$test9,$test10,$test11,$test12,$test13,$test14, $test15,$test16,$test17,$test18);
$stmt->execute(array($test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6,$test7,$test8,$test9,$test10,$test11,$test12,$test13,$test14,$test15, $test16,$test17,$test18
));
```

And the line 58 would be:

```
));
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

You don't provide the values when calling `execute`, you provided them when you called `bind_param`.

It seems like you're confusing mysqli with PDO.

Comment: thanks it worked, also is there a way to implement two $stmts for example: one that prepares to update a user file by query and one that does this code.

Comment: You can prepare as many statements as you want. If you want both `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, I suspect what you really should use is `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  `test_table`(datenow,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8, 
test9,test10,test11,test12,test14,test15,test16,test17,test18,) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") 
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss',$test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6,$test7,$test8,$test9,$test10,$test11,$test12,$test13,$test14, $test15,$test16,$test17,$test18);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->execute();
```

That is enough already mate.

Comment: According to the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php , it's possible to pass in parameters when calling `execute`. The documentation seems to be wrong, but that's why people are doing it.